# is there faulty code to save logged user in laravel in my code?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am trying to save logged user in pay table. another function run properly, but I am still unable to save current user to database/table.

so far I already tried to use this code in function store:

```
$pay = new Pay;
$pay->cde_user = Auth::user()->id;
```

below detail code from my PayController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Contract;
use App\Pay;
use App\User;
use Auth;

class PayController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $pay = Pay::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('pay.index',compact('pay'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);

    }

    public function create()
    {
        $contract = Contract::all();
        return view('pay.create', compact('contract'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'cde_contract',
            'party1' => 'required',
            'party2' => 'required',
        ]);

        $pay = new Pay;
        $pay->cde_user = Auth::user()->id;

        Pay::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('pay.index')
                        ->with('success','STORED');

    }

    public function edit(Pay $pay)
    {
        return view('pay.edit',compact('pay'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Pay $pay)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'cde_contract',
            'party1' => 'required',
            'party2' => 'required',
        ]);

        $pay->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('pay.index')
                        ->with('success','PAY UPDATED');
    }

    public function destroy(Pay $pay)
    {
        $pay->delete();
        return redirect()->route('pay.index')
        ->with('success','PAY DELETED');
    }
}
```

Is there an error from my store and update function?

How do I save current logged in user using Laravel?

[image: try to save user id to shown field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the store function you have to decide if you are going to use the `create()` method or `new Pay` and then the `save()` method:

```
$pay = new Pay;
$pay->cde_user = Auth::user()->id;
$pay->cde_contract = $request->cde_contract;
$pay->party1 = $request->party1;
$pay->party2 = $request->party2;
$pay->save();
```

or

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['cde_user'] = Auth::user()->id;
Pay::create($data);
```

And in update function you need to add the user->id to the data you want to update:

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['cde_user'] = Auth::user()->id;
$pay->update($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Here is small mistake you did in store function

**Solution 1:**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'cde_contract',
            'party1' => 'required',
            'party2' => 'required',
        ]);

        $pay = new Pay;
        $pay->cde_user = Auth::user()->id;

        $pay->save(); /* correction, remove Pay::create(... line from your code */

        return redirect()->route('pay.index')
                        ->with('success','STORED');

    }
```

**Solution 2:**
 Note: Make sure you define all field in  `Pay` Model fillable array.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'cde_contract',
            'party1' => 'required',
            'party2' => 'required',
        ]);


        $data = $request->all();
        $data["cde_user"]  = Auth::user()->id;
        Pay::create($data);

        return redirect()->route('pay.index')
                        ->with('success','STORED');

    }
```